# LVS persistence

Tags: lvs

I install LVS with persistence.
It's work well but I would like to understand the persistence.
For me, all the client with the same address ip will go to the same server until the end of the timeout.
But what's happened if clients are behind a provider/proxy/firewall or public addresses?
Does they all go to the same real server?
if yes the load balancing isn't really useful in this case, so how it's possible to handle sessions correctly?